# Differentiating a summation with respect to a particular index

Tags: derivatives, summation, tensors, summation-method, kronecker-delta

Consider the following Lagrangian:

$$L = \sqrt{g_{ij}\dot{X^i} \dot{X^j}}$$

Note that in the above Lagrangian we have taken the Einstein Summation convention and the metric $g_{ij}$ is a function of the coordinates $X^i$.

I need help in understanding how to deduce $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{X^k}}$.

If someone could explain the following steps my textbook take I would greatly appreciate it. I am specifically stuck on why the Kronecker delta symbol appears and how the solution proceeds with using it so an explanation would be really helpful:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{X^k}} = \frac{1}{2L}g_{ij}(\delta^i_k \ \dot{X^j} +   \ \dot{X^i} 
 \delta^j_k ) = \frac{1}{L}g_{ki} \dot{X^i}$

Comment: Try  doing the derivative without the root. Note that $\partial x_a \over \partial x_b $ vanishes if $a\neq b$ and is 1 if $a=b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We denote $X_k \equiv x_k$ for brevity. Then,
$$L = \sqrt{g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j}$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial\dot{x}_k}=\frac{1}{2L}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{x}_k}\left(g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j\right)=\frac{1}{2L}\left(g_{ij}\dot{x}_j\frac{\partial\dot{x}_i}{\partial\dot{x}_k}+g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\frac{\partial\dot{x}_j}{\partial\dot{x}_k}\right)\tag{1}$$
We also have
$$\frac{\partial\dot{x}_i}{\partial\dot{x}_j}=\delta_{ij}$$
since $\dot{x}_i$ and $\dot{x}_j$ are independent for $i\ne j$. With this simplification, $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial\dot{x}_k}=\frac{1}{2L}\left(g_{ij}\dot{x}_j\frac{\partial\dot{x}_i}{\partial\dot{x}_k}+g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\frac{\partial\dot{x}_j}{\partial\dot{x}_k}\right) &= \frac{1}{2L}\left(g_{ij}\dot{x}_j\delta_{ik}+g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\delta_{jk}\right)\\ &=\frac{1}{2L}\left(g_{kj}\dot{x}_j+g_{ik}\dot{x}_i\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{L}g_{ij}\dot{x}_i\end{align}$$
We have also used the fact that $g_{ij}$ is symmetric in $i$ and $j$ and that $g_{ij}$ is a function of the coordinates $x_k$ only.

PS: Raised and lowered indices have not been used to avoid confusion.